# How do I run bibtex after using the -output-directory flag with pdflatex, when files are included from subdirectories?

Tags: bibtex, compiling, auxiliary-files, folders

When I have master pdflatex file which includes one or more child documents using something like `\include{include/childdoc}`, and I call pdflatex on it using `pdflatex -output-directory=out parent.tex`, I seem unable to find a way of calling bibtex on the resulting `parent.aux` file.  I have tried both `cd out; bibtex parent`, and `bibtex out/parent`, to no avail.

I know there are various build-tools out there, but I'd like first to make it work just from the shell with no special build-tool dependencies.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Ok I finally figured it out (not sure if this is documented somewhere already):

I needed to explicitly create directories within `out` having the same name as the directories I include files from.  Then, I need to be in the `out` directory when running bibtex.  Furthermore, the bibtex file needs to be manually copied to the `out` directory. Finally, I run pdflatex a second time from the top-level directory, again with the -output-directory flag.

In summary (starting in the directory containing `parent.tex`):

1. `mkdir out/include`
2. `pdflatex -output-directory=out parent.tex`
3. `cp mybib.bib out`
4. `cd out ; bibtex parent`
5. `cd .. ; pdflatex -output-directory=out parent.tex`

(and maybe you need to run pdflatex again, depending on what packages you're using...)

Comment: Is there no way to get around copying the file?

Comment: There IS a way to get around copying the file, but it kind of sucks. When giving the \bibliography{...} command, give the paths to the .bib files relative to the output directory. So if are planning on running `pdflatex -output-directory=out`, say `\bibliography{../mybib}` instead of `\bibliography{mybib}`. (You still have to run `bibtex` from the output directory, unfortunately. If using a Unixy shell, you can say `(cd out; bibtex parent)` (parentheses included!) and avoid having to `cd ..` when you're done.)

Comment: There is a way around copying the .bib file. You just need to set the environment variable BIBINPUTS to the directory where your .bib file is located: export BIBINPUTS=/path/to/directory/of/bibfile Now you can just run bibtex without copying the file.

Answer (score 10):

You can use environment variable TEXMFOUTPUT to specify output directory for bibtex files. In your case, you can create makefile like:

```
all:
    mkdir out -p
    pdflatex -output-directory out parent.tex
    TEXMFOUTPUT="out:" bibtex out/parent
    pdflatex -output-directory out parent.tex
    pdflatex -output-directory out parent.tex
```

Consider a more complicated variant where you have placed your source files in subdirectory `src`. Then you will use also variable BIBINPUTS to specify locations of your *.bib files and BSTINPUTS to specify location of your *.bst files (bibliography style). Then the makefile could look like this:

```
all:
    mkdir out -p
    TEXINPUTS="src:" pdflatex -output-directory out src/parent.tex
    BIBINPUTS="src:" BSTINPUTS="out:" TEXMFOUTPUT="out:" bibtex out/parent
    TEXINPUTS="src:" pdflatex -output-directory out src/parent.tex
    TEXINPUTS="src:" pdflatex -output-directory out src/parent.tex
```

Comment: bibtex only puts its output in TEXMFOUTPUT (if it can't do so in the current directory), but doesn't look for inputs (aux files) there. This didn't work for me with TeX Live 2013 (bibtex 0.99d)

Comment: See my answer for a fix :) Two years late, sorry

Answer (score 6):

If you are using TexStudio, there is a simple way to do it. In Preferences/Commands, you can add to the BibTeX line `build/%.aux` if your output folder for PdfLaTeX is named `build`.

This is working for me with `my_bibliography.bib` in the same folder as my LaTeX files and using the following at the end of my LaTeX file.

```
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{bibliography}
```

I guess you can find similar settings for other editors/compilers.

Hope this helps !

Comment: This doesn't seem to work if you \include files. I ended up using `sh -c "cp references.bib build;cd build;bibtex %.aux"`. This copies the bib file to the build folder and runs bibtex with the build folder as current directory.

Answer (score 5):

The procedure suggested by @framerius works, but requires a little hack. I will summarize his answer here as well, for completeness.

The issue is that bibtex ability to write to $TEXMFOUTPUT is restricted to avoid file overwriting and the bibtex command returns an error message

```
bibtex: Not writing to  $TEXMFOUTPUT/src.blg (openout_any = p).
```

Open the file `texmf.cnf`, dunno about windows, but on linux:

```
/usr/share/texlive/texmf/web2c/texmf.cnf (UBUNTU TEXLIVE)
/usr/share/texmf-dist/web2c/texmf.cnf (ARCH LINUX TEXLIVE)
```

find the `openout_any = p` line and change it either to `a` for always or `r` for restricted (p stands for paranoid fyi).

Now, running something like

```
mkdir OUT
TEXMFOUTPUT="OUT"
pdflatex --output-directory OUT myfile
bibtex OUT/myfile
pdflatex --output-directory OUT myfile
pdflatex --output-directory OUT myfile
```

produces the expected results, and is fully scriptable. The hack comes from this page [Bibtex going openout](http://jansoehlke.com/2012/09/bibtex-going-openout_any-p/) which I googled. Enjoy clean folders forever and ever =D

Comment: this does not work for me (Ubuntu 14.04)

Answer (score 3):

Did you check the location of the aux-files? The  --output-directory doesn't affect auxiliary files (at least not in miktex. In miktex there is the --aux-directory switch to set the directory for auxiliary files). Also - as you use `\include`: Don't forget that they will be more than one aux-file.

Comment: Unlike miktex, pdflatex's `-output-directory=xyz` switch causes everything (including aux files) to be placed beneath `xyz`.

Answer (score 0):

The solution of Emilie Picard-Cantin works great as long as you (use TexStudio and) do not `\include{}` files into the file that you compile. The auxiliary file of the included file is placed next to the included file, instead of in the build directory. This results in bibtex not being able to find the generated .aux file. Using `\input{}` instead of `\include{}` makes everything work like a charm.