# VSCode plug LaTeX Workshop generates all my main.tex aux files to my project's root dir

Tags: latex-workshop

I'm using LaTeX Workshop with VSCode. Currently, the auxillary files (.aux, .bbl, ...) are generated into my top directory. I'd rather generate them to a subdirectory to keep my root dir clean.

I see in the plugin settings that I can specify several directories for searching for files but I don't see a setting for where to put generated files.

I know I can specify one when building from the CLI. E.g., `pdflatex -aux-directory=DIR -output-directory=DIR filename.tex` but how would I do the equivalent from within VSCode?

Comment: I never use `--output-directory`. If I want to keep the source folder clean, I use l3build to move all files before the compilation to a dedicated build folder. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/673007/2388

Comment: Thanks @UlrikeFischer. I tried running `l3build clean` but got `Error: Cannot find configuration build.lua`. I'm reading the docs but don't see what goes into a `build.lua` file. Am I running the wrong command params? If not, can you point me to a sample `build.lua` file?