# Using the package memoize with a specified --output-directory

Tags: forest, memoize

I'm trying to configure the package memoize, but am running into issues when trying to pass an --output-directory option to LuaLatex. From looking at the output files and how they end up, it looks as though memoize is mistakenly writing to the output directory, but not reading from it. With the MWE below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[memo dir]{memoize}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Charis SIL}

\begin{document}
A test document. 

\begin{forest}
[S
    [NP]
    [VP]
]
\end{forest}


\end{document}
```

The package works correctly with the simple command `lualatex untitled.tex`, however fails with `lualatex --output-directory=output untitled.tex` with the generic error.

I've also tried adding `\mmzset{prefix=output/}` to no avail.

Comment: well one more reason not to use --output-directory. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/673007/2388

Comment: using `--output-directory` makes everything far more complicated, you have to configure every related program to find where the files have been hidden and has no real advantages at all.

Comment: Which version of `memoize` do you have? For 1.1.2 did you read footnote 68 on page 86?

Comment: The problem seems to be that different parts of the code are using or not using the output directory. In particular, you get two `.mmz.log` files: one in the top level directory and one in the output directory. Moreover, Memoize complains extraction fails even when there is nothing to extract on the first run. I suggest reporting this as a bug. I also third the suggestions not to use `--output-directory`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good news: Memoize actually supports `--output-directory`, or more precisely, it will support it once TeXLive 2024 is released.  Let me explain.

Memoize's extraction scripts respect the value of environment variable `TEXMF_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` which *will* be introduced by TeXLive 2024 (so, very soon!).  (The new variable was in fact conceived as a solution to Memoize's problem with `--output-directory`, and I'm very grateful to Karl Berry for figuring out the solution and implementing it!)  In TeXLive 2024, (a) setting `TEXMF_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` will be an alternative to specifying `--output-directory`, and (b) however the output directory is set, its value will be reflected by the environment variable `TEXMF_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` received by the embedded jobs (like Memoize extraction script).  Bottomline: in 11 days,
things will work out of the box.

Meanwhile, the workaround is to set `TEXMF_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` manually:

```
TEXMF_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=output lualatex --output-directory=output untitled.tex
```

Now the **bad news**: while this was tested and works with the `pdftex` engine, it appears it does not work with `luatex`.  Or rather, things work fine insofar as the externs are correctly produced and extracted,  but utilizing the externs fails, as `lualatex` does not search for them in the output directory (unlike `pdflatex`). I will investigate asap.

A workaround could be to soft-link the memo directory from the output directory into the current directory, but I realize that the OP's setup might not allow for this. From the directory containing `untitled.tex` run:

```
ln -s output/untitled.memo.dir
```

Comment: Another work around for the `lualatex` problem: Set the environment variable `TEXINPUTS` to include the output directory, i.e., `TEXINPUTS=output:`. (Don't forget the `:`.)  Alternatively, use latexmk to compile with the option `-pdflua`; that works since to support the output directory, latexmk does the necessary setting of `TEXINPUTS` (and some other variables).

Comment: Correction to my previous comment: Currently, latexmk doesn't always do enough compilations for a document that uses memoize.  So using latexmk is (not yet) a valid solution.

Comment: It would be fantastic if `latexmk` recompiled when Memoize produces a new extern. In fact, this is partially why Memoize issues a warning at the end of the document when it produces new externs: `Package memoize Warning: The compilation produced <N> new extern(s)`

Comment: The end-of-run message could indeed be used by latexmk to provoke a rerun, but that would need a modification of latexmk itself.  It would probably be useful to make a modification.  Meanwhile, as you've seen, I've provided an answer that involves an unmodified latexmk and a special configuration.

Comment: Okay that's good to hear! I should be able to avoid having too many trees in one doc until then.

Answer (score 2):

I would add to Sašo Živanović's answer that it is possible to configure latexmk to use memoize with an output directory.

Here's what goes in a latexmkrc file.
**(NOTE that an improved version of this configuration will be in the next version of latexmk (v. 4.84).  The solution here works only with TeXLive on Unix-type OSs (linux and macOS), and only when latexmk uses lualatex for pdflatex for the compilation of the .tex file.)**

```
$pdf_mode = 4;  # Use lualatex.  Set to 1 for pdflatex, 5 for xelatex.

# You can have separate build and output directories, or they can be
# the same, e.g., by $out_dir = $aux_dir = 'output';
$out_dir = 'output';
$aux_dir = 'build';
$emulate_aux = 1;

# Get latexmk -C to delete memoize-generated files, at least
# when the default setting in memoize for the prefix of .memo
# and .pdf files is used.
push @generated_exts, 'mmz', 'mmz.log', '%R.*.memo', '%R.*.pdf';
&set_tex_cmds( 'internal latex_memoize %C %B %S -synctex=1 %O' );

sub latex_memoize {
  print "============= I am latex_memoize \n";
  # Ensure TEX_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY is set. (In v. >=4.84 of latexmk, this
  # will not be necessary, since latexmk will make the setting itself.)
  local %ENV = %ENV;
  foreach ( 'TEXMF_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY' ) {
    $ENV{$_} = $aux_dir;
    print "latex_memoize: ENV{$_} = '$ENV{$_}'\n";
  }

  my ($cmd, $base, $source, @args) = @_;
  my $tex_log = "$aux_dir1$base.log";
  my $mmz_file = "$aux_dir1$base.mmz";
  my @tex_cmd = ($cmd, @args, $source );
  my @memo_cmd = ("memoize-extract.pl", '-F', 'latex', $mmz_file );

  print "latex_memoize: Running\n  '@tex_cmd'\n";
  my $ret = system @tex_cmd;

  if (! -e $mmz_file) {
    print "latex_memoize: No mmz file '$mmz_file', so memoize is not being used.\n";
    return $ret;
  }

  # Use (not-currently-documented) latexmk subroutine to determine
  #   whether mmz file was generated in current run: 
  if ( ! test_gen_file_time( $mmz_file) ) {
    warn "latex_memoize: Mmz file '$mmz_file' exists, but wasn't generated\n",
         "  in this run so memoize is not **currently** being used.\n";
    return $ret;
  }

  # Fix up dependency information in log file:
  my $mmz_fh = undef;
  my $tex_log_fh = undef;
  if (! open( $mmz_fh, '<', $mmz_file ) ) {
    print "latex_memoize: Cannot open mmz file '$mmz_file':\n $!\n";
    return $ret;
  }
  if (! open( $tex_log_fh, '>>', $tex_log ) ) {
    warn "latex_memoize: Cannot open log file '$tex_log': $!\n";
    close $mmz_fh;
    return $ret;
  }
  while ( <$mmz_fh> ) {
    s/\s*$//;
    my $source = undef;
    if ( /^\\mmzNewExtern\s+{([^}]+)}/ ) {
      # We have a new memo item without a corresponding pdf file
      # Put a suitable message in the log file, so that latexmk will
      # know to run *latex again, when it analyzes the results of 
      # the current run.
      $file = "$aux_dir1$1";
      print "latex_memoize: new extern for memoize: '$file'\n";
      print $tex_log_fh "No file $file\n";
    }
  }
  close $tex_log_fh;
  close $mmz_fh;

  # Run memoize-extract.pl now.  Then missing pdf files are
  # created, which will provoke latexmk into rerunning *latex.
  # It also handles the case that the memoize package is used
  # with the external=no option.  (But gives no problem when
  # the option is not used.)
  # It also allows the use of separate aux and output directories
  # which would otherwise give a problem, since in that situation
  # latexmk will move the pdf file from the aux directory to the
  # output directory, where it is no longer accessible to 
  # memoize-extract.pl.
  print "Running\n @memo_cmd\n";
  my $ret2 = system @memo_cmd;
  if ($ret2) { return $ret2; }

  return $ret;
}
```

This has been tested on TeXLive 2023 and 2024, and with all of pdflatex, lualatex, and xelatex.  (On Windows, there may be some issues when files have non-ASCII characters in their names, but I haven't yet checked.)

As mentioned in comments to the question, there are some complications in working with an output directory.  Ways to get things working are already programmed into latexmk; that was done many years ago and was quite simple, but not something you'd want to do regularly from the command line. I've found that the use of latexmk insulates me against the difficulties that were mentioned.

Comment: A complication with `push @generated_exts`: `.memo` and extern `.pdf` files don't necessarily begin with `%R`. These filenames are configurable, via key `prefix`.

Comment: Agreed.  In clean-up operations, current latexmk is not able to handle the situation with a general prefix.  But it seemed useful to at least handle the default situation within latexmk.